# Is it possible to test a destroy function for a link list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have created a link list program that performs several functions.  I've written a function to destroy the list that takes "top" as a parameter.  I eventually use this function in my destructor.  Can I actually test this?

Here is my shortened Family.h:

```
#ifndef FAMILY_H
#define FAMILY_H

#include<string>
using namespace std;

#include "Child.h"
#include "Wife.h"
#include "Husband.h"

class Family
{
 protected:
  HusPtr top;
  void Destroy(HusPtr& top); //I know in order to access this in the Main, I'd have to make 
                             //this Public.  But I'd have to create a local pointer named top.
                             //Because the local pointer points to nothing, I get a segmentation
                             //fault.
 public:
  Family();
  Family(HusPtr& h);
  Family(const Family& source);
  ~Family();
 };
#endif
```

Here is my Destroy function in my Family.cpp:

```
void Family::Destroy(HusPtr& top)
{
  HusPtr curr = top;
  WifePtr w = curr->myWife;

  while(curr != NULL)
    {
      if(curr->myWife != NULL)
        {
          while(w->myChildren != NULL)
            {
              ChildPtr c = w->myChildren;
              ChildPtr cNext = c->mySibling;
              w->myChildren = cNext;
              delete c;
            }
          curr->myWife = NULL;
          delete w;
        }
      HusPtr next = curr;
      curr = next->nextFamily;
      delete next;
      top = curr;
    }
}
```

My Main.cpp:

```
using namespace std;

#include "Family.h"
HusPtr top; //points to nothing.

int main()
{
  Family F1;
  F1.ProcessTransaction("transaction.txt");
  F1.Destroy(top);// gives a segmentation fault...likely due to the fact that top points to nothing.
}
```

Wife.h:

```
#ifndef HUSBAND_H
#define HUSBAND_H

#include<string>
using namespace std;

#include "Person.h"

class Husband;
typedef Husband* HusPtr;
class Wife;
typedef Wife* WifePtr;

class Husband:public Person
{
  friend class Wife;
  friend class Family;

 protected:
  HusPtr nextFamily;
  WifePtr myWife;

 public:
  Husband();
  Husband(long hSSN, string hFirst, string hLast);
  void Print() const;
};

#endif
```

Wife.h:

```
#ifndef WIFE_H
#define WIFE_H

#include<string>
using namespace std;

#include "Person.h"
#include "Child.h"

class Child;
typedef Child* ChildPtr;

class Wife:public Person
{
  friend class Family;

 protected:
  ChildPtr myChildren;

 public:
  Wife();
  Wife(long wSSN, string wFirst, string wLast);
  void Print() const;
};


#endif
```

Child.h:

```
#ifndef CHILD_H
#define CHILD_H

#include<string>
using namespace std;

#include "Person.h"

class Child;
typedef Child* ChildPtr;

class Child:public Person
{
  friend class Family;

 protected:
  ChildPtr mySibling;

 public:
  Child();
  Child(long cSSN, string cFirst, string cLast);
  void Print() const;
};

#endif
```

This is not a needed function in this assignment, but I decided to implement it anyway.  Everything maps out fine and should work, but I really think that **the segmentation fault I receive is due to the fact that I'm passing a pointer created in Main.cpp that isn't pointing anywhere**.  Am I correct?

Comment: What are `HusPtr`, `ChildPtr`, `WifePtr`? How did you allocated them in main? Post more information.

Comment: HusPtr is a pointer that points to a Husband Node (I have a Husband class). ChildPtr points to a Child Node (Child class).  WifePtr points to a Wife Node(Wife class).  They are in other classes.  The only thing I do in the main is create an object of Family, process a transaction file, and attempt to call the destroy function. I have five classes in total.

Comment: Where did you assign values to `top`?

Comment: I guess you're asking to see a snippet of my Family.cpp file.  Top is pointing to the Husband Node.  After I add a new Husband, top is assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

In second iteration after deleting w, you are not assigning it again. But you try to access its children again. so it get crashed.

in while loop

first iteration 
...
delete w;

second iteration

w->children; program will be crashed.

Comment: That actually resolved the issue!  I ended up defining WifePtr w in the if-statement, then setting curr->myWife = NULL, then deleting w. Good call!!  Pointers can be tricky.

Comment: In this scenario I have seen it in your code itself. But most of the time we don't see that. So try to use a debugger and familiarize with it.

Comment: I'm using emacs...not sure if that's what the program is called or not.  It doesn't catch errors beforehand...a feature that would be awesome.  I guess I could've imported it into Visual C++ though.

Comment: Emacs is the editor. But debugger comes with compiler(development package). It should have a debugger with it. ex g++ -> gdb.

Comment: Why am I finding out about this at the end of the semester?? It definitely wouldn't been helpful early on.  Thanks for the info though.  Even though this is my last CS class, I'm sure I'll run into it again in the future.

Comment: please consider accepting my answer using the 'tick' button on the left

Comment: I up ticked as soon as I made the change in my program.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42514/discussion-between-amald-and-kevin-simpson-ii)